# function already has a body and redefinition of string variable

Tags: c++

ERRORS:
[error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T46dl.png)

mainFun.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "userCheckFunH.h"
using namespace std;

int yesNo;
string passName;
string userName;

string userRetrieve()
{

    if (userName == "")
    {
        cin >> userName;
    }
    else
    {
        if (userName == "devin772" || userName == "guestacc")
        {
            yesNo = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            yesNo = 0;
        }

    }
    return userName;
}
int userCheck()
{
    return yesNo;
}


int main()
{
    do
    {
        string userN;
        system("cls");
        // ui
        cout << "      DH DB     " << endl;
        cout << "x----------------x" << endl;
        //username 
        cout << "username: " << endl;
        cout << "> ";
        // fun call
        userRetrieve();
        int continueP = userCheck();
        cout << "" << endl;

        // password
        if (continueP = 1 && userRetrieve() == "devin772")
        {
            cout << "password:" << endl;
            cout << "> ";
            cin >> passName;
            if (passName == "12qwaszx")
            {
                cout << "" << endl;
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                // run program
                dataBaseRunP("admin");
                npOpen();
                cout << "" << endl;
                system("pause");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else if (continueP = 1 && userRetrieve() == "guestacc")
        {
            cout << "password:" << endl;
            cout << "> ";
            cin >> passName;
            if (passName == "guestguest")
            {
                cout << "" << endl;
                system("pause");
                system("cls");
                // run program
                dataBaseRunP("regUser");
                npOpen();
                cout << "" << endl;
                system("pause");
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Invalid username." << endl;
            cout << "" << endl;
            system("pause");
            userRetrieve() = "";
            userName = "";
            yesNo = 0;
            passName = "";
        }
    } while (true);
    system("pause");
}
```

nextFun.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "userCheckFunH.h"
using namespace std;

string userLevel;

int dataBaseRunP(string authLevel)
{
    string fileName;
    if (authLevel == "regUser")
    {
        fileName = "user.txt";
        userLevel = fileName;
    }
    else if (authLevel == "admin")
    {
        fileName = "admin.txt";
        userLevel = fileName;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "ERROR - user level not found." << endl;
        system("pause");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        return 0;
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    return 0;
}

void npOpen()
{
    string fileNpName;
    fileNpName = userLevel;
    fileNpName = "notepad \"" + fileNpName + "\"";
    system(fileNpName.c_str());
}
```

userCheckFunH.h:

```
#ifndef USERCHECKFUN_H
#define USERCHECKFUN_H
#include "nextFun.cpp"
 int dataBaseRunP();
 void npOpen();
#endif
```

i'm attempting to make a basic program that allows you to open files hidden through windows in a basic c++ program. keep getting this error. tried different header guards, variable names, function names, file names. i also delete nextFun.cpp and the program ran fine. i can't get past this error, please help.
thanks! :)

Comment: `#include "nextFun.cpp"` - never include a .cpp file.

Comment: "i can't get past this error" - *What* error? You don't show any error messages in your question. Copy the *entire* error message (*verbatim*) into the question.

Comment: @JesperJuhl sorry, im new to this. the question's been edited

Comment: Please put the error messages *in* the question as *text*. Please never link to external images of code or error messages or anything else that's critical to the question. External links tend to go stale and images are not searchable. Also; I'm sure the compiler actually gave more output than the 3 line summary in that image.

Comment: @JesperJuhl It did not, it just got cut by the screenshot on the top one. Will convert the errors to text now.

Comment: Are you *sure* there's not another output window with the raw text? I'm *fairly* sure there is  If not, then invoking the compiler directly from a command prompt *will* give more output there.

Comment: @JesperJuhl made a new project and copied all the code over, everything works fine. some hidden file or something must have been in my project folder.

Answer (score 1):

It is highly unusual to include a cpp file, which you do in userCheckFunH.h, with

```
#include "nextFun.cpp"
```

Your nextFun.cpp file includes this very header:

```
#include "userCheckFunH.h"
```

Since you cpp file doesn't have an include guard (which is fine) you end up with the functions in the cpp file twice.

Don't include the cpp file in the header.

Comment: i will try, thank you   EDIT: i'm now getting an error where it says the functions in my header file can not be found.

Comment: The "functions" - as in all of them? This sounds like a new problem, and therefore a new question. Ask a new question, and make sure to put the exact error. (Is this from the linker?)

Comment: the dataBaseRunP function and I will edit the question with an image of the error

Comment: @absxnt If you are asking another question, you should probably started a new question.